# Going from database to sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

Well I have my register done all nice, as required fields it holds your email, name, and password. When you log in it asks for your email and password.

When they log in I have it so that they have their email stored in a session, but how do I get their firstname stored in a session, even though they didn't type it? Thanks.

The thing is, I don't know the users first name so...

Comment: When you do the login, pull up the first name from the database and stuff it into the session?

Comment: I've tried pulling up the firstname but it won't work. What's the code for it?

Comment: I'm too confused. Is this database connection based or session based problem?

Comment: Look it up in your database and set a session variable.

Comment: Can't give you any code without knowing how your tables are set up, but something like `SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE email='someone@example.com'`?

Comment: -1. Your question is too vague. Include more details on what you're trying to do, what your tables look like, what sort of application you're writing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logins in with their username/password and after verification of the information, query the database for their record. Set the returned value(s) into the session. If you are already getting information about the account, add a table join (if in separate tables) or the columns.

Comment: I try that, but it never works. I don't think I'm querying it right. What would be the code for it?

Comment: Add some of your code you worked on. It will help people understand what you tried, language you used and what you need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When they log in and you are checking the login credentials (email and password), if you find the user, select their first name as well and store it in another session variable:

```
$query = 'SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE email = $email AND password = $password LIMIT 1';
...
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row->firstname;
    ...
```

That might not be exact based on table and column names, but that's the general idea.