# How do you run a query to find ALL data in a row?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Going from database to sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418881/going-from-database-to-sessions)

A user enters information, which I stored in the variable $email.

I need to find out this users first and last name every time they log in. It's stored in the table Persons, but I need it to be stored into a variable.

For example, someone logged in using the e-mail Example@example.com. I need to find out their firstname and lastname that they signed up with.

Don't say to type in the email manually, because I need it to be automatic when a user logs in

Comment: Sorry, but that's basic SQL and PHP. You should learn how to do that on your own. And yes, this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Are you asking how to do a query to the database? it's not really clear...Also, you asked 3 questions and all got downvoted, you should really improve the way you ask questions (showing efforts, code, useful info)

Comment: It's because I'm the author of Going from database to sessions :/

Comment: @user1227430 and all 3 questions are around the same [basic] code; have a look at the php manual, while you're at it, it's really helpful. People here like to help, but you can't ask them to write all your website for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insufficient info, I'm afraid. If you, for example, store firstnames in 'firstname' column, lastnames in 'lastname', and email in, most creatively, 'email' the query will look like:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Persons WHERE email = '$email'
```

But it's really just a beginning of the solution. )

Comment: Actually that's what it seems to be the answer when I think about that query. Thanks!!

Comment: And yes, the column that holds emails does have a creative name. It's email XDD

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, email 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE 
        email = 'example@example.com' 
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Persons WHERE email = 'Example@example.com' LIMIT 1
```

If you need all Persons data

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE email = 'Example@example.com' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is one of your tags, I'm guessing you're after some PHP code...

So you've got $email with the user's email. Assuming you're already connected to your database and your database table 'Persons' has columns named firstname, lastname and email, the PHP code is:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email); //look up SQL injection
$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Persons WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if ($userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $firstName = $userData['firstname'];
   $lastName = $userData['lastname'];
} else {
   echo "User not found";
}
```

Comment: You can use mysql_fetch_assoc() also. And put an error check for mysql_query(). And maybe use mysqli, or PDO.

Comment: I didn't know about mysql_fetch_assoc()! Thanks